# Как добавить произвольное поле к записи, чтобы оно отображалось на сайте и в админке?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как добавить произвольное поле к записи, чтобы оно отображалось на сайте и в админке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему плагином Advanced Custom Fields

Вывожу значение полей на страницах Wordpress с помощью shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('answer', 'answer');
function answer(){
    global $post;
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'answer')){
        $answer = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'answer');
        var_dump($answer);
        $output = '<ul>';
        foreach ($answer as $key => $value) {
            $output .= "<li>$key</li><ul>";
            for ($i=0; $i < count($value); $i++) { 
                $output .= "<li>$value[$i]</li>";
            }
        }
        $output .= '</ul></ul>';
        return $output;
        unset($output);
        unset($answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Метаполя - стандартный функционал WordPress, плагины для этого не нужны. ACF создаёт лишь дополнительный сервис.

Comment: @KAGGDesign На произвольных записях у меня не работает стандартный функционал произвольных полей WordPress.

Comment: В вопросе о каком-либо функционале ни слова. Отображение на сайте и в админке - работает.